# Kubuntu text trails on window move/scroll

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, kde

Kubuntu 17.10

https://youtu.be/Wx4oql2NZsg

https://youtu.be/CNFzkDvqdEU

Maybe it is not easy to see on video, but I tried my best. As you can see there is white trail on text when scrolling browser or moving windows. I tried turn off all desktop effects in kde no success. Also I install latest nvidia-384 driver and set "Force full composition pipeline" (and tearing gone), but this "trail" effect still present.

Comment: Did you screen capture that?  Or did you use a video camera?  If it is a problem with the refresh rate of your monitor, we would not be able to see what you're seeing with using a screen capture.

Comment: Of course this is screen capture. I made it with https://github.com/peek/peek

Comment: @broomrider I think that's the wrong link.

Comment: @wjandrea yes, it is wrong link =) here is right one https://github.com/phw/peek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with monitor internal settings (overdrive). That explains why I saw same artifacts on recorded video too. I turn off overdrive and everything is perfect now.